# Python - SimpleJSON Issue

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I'm working with the Mega API and Python in hope to produce a folder tree readable by Python. At the moment I'm working with the JSON responses Mega's API gives, but for some reason am having trouble parsing it. In the past I would simply use simplejson in the format below, though right now it's not working. At the moment I'm just trying to get the file name. Any help is appreciated!

```
import simplejson    

megaResponseToFileSearch = "(u'BMExefXbYa', {u'a': {u'n': u'A Bullet For Pretty Boy - 1 - Dial M For Murder.mp3'}, u'h': u'BMExXbYa', u'k': (5710166, 21957970, 11015946, 7749654L), u'ts': 13736999, 'iv': (7949460, 15946811, 0, 0), u'p': u'4FlnwBTb', u's': 5236864, 'meta_mac': (529642, 2979591L), u'u': u'xpz_tb-YDUg', u't': 0, 'key': (223xx15874, 642xx8505, 1571620, 26489769L, 799460, 1596811, 559642, 279591L)})"

jsonRespone = simplejson.loads(megaResponseToFileSearch)

print jsonRespone[u'a'][u'n']
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/Mega Sync/megasync.py", line 18, in <module>
    jsonRespone = simplejson.loads(file4)
  File "D:\Projects\Mega Sync\simplejson\__init__.py", line 453, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Projects\Mega Sync\simplejson\decoder.py", line 429, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "D:\Projects\Mega Sync\simplejson\decoder.py", line 451, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

EDIT:

I was asked where I got the string from. It's a response to searching for a file using the Mega API. I'm using the module found here. https://github.com/richardasaurus/mega.py
The code itself looks like this:

```
from mega import Mega
mega = Mega({'verbose': True})
m = mega.login(email, password)
file = m.find('A Bullet For Pretty Boy - 1 - Dial M For Murder.mp3')
print file
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid json string. Where did you get it (post the code if possible)?

Comment: Updated question with code. Was it too quick of me to assume it was JSON it was spitting out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are getting from `m.find` is just a python tuple, where the 1-st (next after the 0th) element is a dictionary:

```
(u'99M1Tazb',
 {u'a': {u'n': u'test.txt'}, 
  u'h': u'99M1Tazb', 
  u'k': (1145485578, 1435138417, 702505527, 274874292), 
  u'ts': 1373482712,
  'iv': (1883603069, 763415510, 0, 0), 
  u'p': u'9td12YaY', 
  u's': 0, 
  'meta_mac': (1091379956, 402442960),
  u'u': u'79_166PAQCA', 
  u't': 0,
  'key': (872626551, 2013967015, 1758609603, 127858020, 1883603069, 763415510, 1091379956, 402442960)})
```

To get the filename, just use:

```
print file[1]['a']['n']
```

So, no need to use `simplejson` at all.

Comment: AH! That's why I got mixed up. Thank you very much!